# Showing submenu on mouseenter but disappears on hover

Tags: jquery, css

Couldn't really think of a more appropriate title, you're more than welcome to change it.

I have a fixed left column for navigation. When a user hovers over one of the navigation items in this column, I want to show a sub-menu to the right of the column. My problem is that when the user moves their cursor over to the new sub-menu element it disappears.

This is where I'm at so far but not sure of the best way to resolve this.

[My project's fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CrUx2/)

If you hover over one of my navigation items for more that 1750 milliseconds, you'll see my sub-menu appear - but if you hover over that it disappears! How do I get it to stay there? It's almost as if I need to cancel the `mouseleave` function when hovering the sub-menu... but not sure to...

**My CSS Code:**

```
.page-wrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.nav {
    position:fixed;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:175px;
    background:#111;
    padding:20px 0;
}
.nav-item {
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    padding:0 20px;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:13px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.nav-item:hover {
    background:#222;
}
.submenu {
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    left:175px;
    top:0;
    width:175px;
    height:100%;
    background:#999;
}
```

**My jQuery Code:**

```
var sub_menu_timer;
$('.nav-item').on({
    mouseenter:function() {
        sub_menu_timer = setTimeout(function() {
            $('.submenu').show();
        },1750)
    },
    mouseleave:function() {
        clearTimeout(sub_menu_timer);
        $('.submenu').hide();
    }
})
```

**My HTML Code:**

```
<div class="page-wrapper">
    <div class="submenu"></div>
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="nav-item">
            ITEM 1
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item">
            ITEM 2
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item">
            ITEM 3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is as simple as this

```
$('.nav-item, .submenu').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $('.submenu').show();
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $('.submenu').hide();
    }
});
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CrUx2/2/)

---

Update:

If you want to keep the timeout then, you need to define the functions separately  like this -

```
var sub_menu_timer;
$('.nav-item').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        sub_menu_timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $('.submenu').show();
        }, 1750)
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        clearTimeout(sub_menu_timer);
        $('.submenu').hide();
    }
});


$('.submenu').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $('.submenu').show();
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $('.submenu').hide();
    }
});
```

like shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CrUx2/6/), but now when you move out of `submenu` to `nav-item`, the sub menu goes away and comes after the timeout.

Comment: This is good but how do I get the timer/delay working with this. Maybe the `.sub-menu` will have to have its own mousenter/mouseleave function?

Comment: I see your last point. I think this is something I'll just have to live with. Maybe I could write a little function to check whether the sub-menu is visible before loading it again...

Answer (score 1):

Check out this updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CrUx2/5/).

Using the the mouseleave event on the submenu to hide the submenu will work more like you intended.

The new javascript:

```
var sub_menu_timer;
$('.nav-item').on({
    mouseenter:function() {
        sub_menu_timer = setTimeout(function() {
            $('.submenu').show();
        },1750)
    },
    mouseleave:function() {
        clearTimeout(sub_menu_timer);
    }
});

$('.submenu').on({
    mouseenter:function() {
        $('.submenu').show();
    },
    mouseleave:function() {
        $('.submenu').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: try moving the mouse to `nav-item` and them move out without going on `submenu`.

Comment: Still need to keep the timer though.

Answer (score 0):

The `.submenu` is not a child of the ITEM divs, so when you hover over the submenu you are hovering *out* of the ITEM divs and triggering `.mouseleave`.  The simplest solution is to make corresponding submenus children of the `.nav-item` divs so you will remain hovered over them as long as you are hovered over `.submenu`.  If this is not feasible, you will have to do much more complicated JavaScript handling with respect to mouseleave and the `.submenu` hovering.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this, is by using a list, that way you don't need JS.

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li>ITEM 1
        <ul>
            <li>ITEM 1.1</li>
            <li>ITEM 1.2</li>
            <li>ITEM 1.3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>ITEM 2</li>
    <li>ITEM 3</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav {
    position:fixed;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:175px;
    background:#111;
    padding:20px 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.nav li {
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    padding:0 20px;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:13px;
    cursor:pointer;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}
.nav li:hover {
    background:#222;
}
.nav li ul {
    display: none;
}
.nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position:fixed;
    left:175px;
    top:0;
    width:175px;
    height:100%;
    background:#999;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/FbAf6/).

Comment: doesn't work in internet explorer 6 though because only the `a` tag supports the pseudo-class `hover` (in that browser)

Comment: according to [http://www.ie6countdown.com/](http://www.ie6countdown.com/) 6.1% of the world as of now anyway :)

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I have to use JS really, because when the nav item is hovered, the script grabs a `data-topic` attribute and loads data into the sub-menu using AJAX. I also need the timer/delay as I don't want the sub-menu appearing if the user accidentally runs their cursor over the navigation column.